# Jwplayer Player with Primary html5

Tags: jwplayer

I want to deliver OnDemand Video to our client with Html5 as primary streaming.
Client are using IE and Firefox browsers and adobe player plugin is not installed coz of which video cant be streamed through flash(rtmp) so we have push html5 video streaming.

Code :
jwplayer("myElement").setup({

```
    playlist: [{

    sources: [
      { 
        file: "http://xxxxxxx/vod/mp4:tektr_hssd.mp4/playlist.m3u8",
        type: "mp4",
        primary : html5
    },
   {

        file: "rtmp://xxxxxx/vod/mp4:tek_hssd.mp4" 
    }]
}],

        image: "/uploads/a123.jpg",
            androidhls: "true",
            autostart: true,
            width: "100%",
            aspectratio: "4:3"

        });
```

I m not getting any stream on browser(firefox and IE(8))

Answer (score 3):

An m3u8 is an HLS stream. It can be displayed natively only in Safari, iOS, and Android. In all other desktop browsers, it requires Flash. You can't "push" HTML5 - Chrome, Firefox, and IE can't display an HLS stream in HTML5. And even in Flash, it requires a JW Player Premium license, or higher.

See http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-reference#streaming

Comment: is there any other way to stream the video if client has not installed adobe flash plugin.....or piece of extra code we can write so that it can work?

Comment: Eventually, DASH will probably take care of the problem, but for now you're stuck with Flash. There's no way you can magically make a browser do something it isn't designed to do - you can't change the code of Firefox, for example.

Comment: But visitors using Chrome, Firefox, and IE still need Flash. You can't get around this.

Comment: A Premium JW Player license gives you HLS support on browsers which do not have support for HLS in HTML5 <video> natively, so it renders in Flash. Only Safari on OS X will render the HLS stream in HTML5 mode as far as desktop browsers are concerned.